# css checkbox style for border color

Tags: css, checkbox

**I have a check box in my table. 
this is css of that checkbox**

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    width: 20px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: auto;
    display: table-row;
    border: 5px solid red;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-top: 1px;
}
```

but it shows normal checkbox.
I want to change the border color of that checkbox. 
but it doesn't work!!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can put only below css for checkbox border and see [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/f3ukuvga/)

CSS:

```
.error input[type=checkbox] {
  outline: 2px solid #c00;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this customized the checkbox code:

```css
/* Remove default checkbox */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked),
[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {  
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;

  -webkit-user-select: none; /* webkit (safari, chrome) browsers */
  -moz-user-select: none; /* mozilla browsers */
  -khtml-user-select: none; /* webkit (konqueror) browsers */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
}

/* checkbox aspect */
[type="checkbox"] + label:before,
[type="checkbox"] + label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;

  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: .2s;
}
/* Unchecked styles */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:before {
  top: 0px;
  width: 19px; height: 19px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
  top: 0px;
  width: 19px; height: 19px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  z-index: 0;
}
/* Checked styles */
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  top: 2px;
  width: 6px; height: 12px;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  border-left: 1px solid transparent;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(37deg);
  transform: rotateZ(37deg);

  -webkit-transform-origin: 20% 40%;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  top: 0px;
  width: 19px; height: 19px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  z-index: 0;
}
/* disabled checkbox */
[type="checkbox"]:disabled:not(:checked) + label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked + label:before {
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: #444;
  width: 19px; height: 19px;
  border: 3px solid #444;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  transform: rotateZ(0deg);
}
[type="checkbox"]:disabled + label {
  color: #555;
}
[type="checkbox"]:disabled:not(:checked) + label:hover:before {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
        <p>
          <input type="checkbox" id="test1" />
          <label for="test1">Red</label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <input type="checkbox" id="test2" checked="checked" />
          <label for="test2">Yellow</label>
        </p>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess HTML does not allow adding border styles to check boxes.  Try using the outline property instead.