# How to add CSS styles to checkbox on selection?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make HTML checkboxes have a certain set of CSS styling only when it's been selected. E.g. change colour or change text weight, etc. 
I am confused about whether I should use a function or if there is an existing method that I could use.

I have gone through these questions:

- [css checkbox style for border color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41757006/css-checkbox-style-for-border-color)
- [How to change checkbox's border style in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460501/how-to-change-checkboxs-border-style-in-css)

Comment: You haven't described a problem you're facing other than lack of beauty. Please revise to make it more clear what isn't working as expected.

Comment: Can you provide some example code?

Comment: Related, possibly a dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630229/can-i-have-an-onclick-effect-in-css (I'm out of CVs atm anyway)

Comment: Why dont you try, show us then we can help from there

Comment: I m not asking you to debug some code @BLAKE ,what I m asking is a way to code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any function for this, you can do this with good understanding of [css selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

You can try:

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked+span {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    color:red;
}
```

and define your text box like

```
<input type="checkbox" ><span>Some text label for checkbox</span>
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wu5y69)

Comment: yes but this is not the proper way to ask a question you better first give it a try as 
@DanStarns said

Comment: and then search for what problem you faced, there are lots of answer to this question, as one mentioned by @TylerH above

Comment: yeah I understand but as I said I am new to stack overflow, I wouldn't repeat it again

Answer (score 1):

You can control the styling of checkboxes or other inputs based on their current state through CSS selectors like this:

```
input[type='checkbox'] {background-color:red;}

input[type='checkbox']:checked {background-color:blue;}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, use a function that you would call the onclick method on.

Example:

```
<div>
<p id ="color" onclick="changeFunction()">This text can change colors</p>
<button id="changeColor" onclick="changeFunction()"> Click Me</button>
</div>
<script>
function changeFunction(){
var words = document.getElementById('color');
words.style.color = 'red';
}
</script>
```

Here's a working Jsfiddle to show you this example: https://jsfiddle.net/z4gr8wn5/

This should give you a base idea of how you should go forward with figuring out what you need to find out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking on how to change a checkbox style when the user clicks then this will help you out https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_custom_checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Making use of the `:checked` css pseudo-class you will be able to change the element style without using Javascript.

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:checked).

```css
/* Change color */
input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px red;
}

/* Change label color */
input:checked+label {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="my-checkbox" id="example">
<label for="example">Check me!</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you want to toggle a class, and here is a example if that is the case.

```
<style>
  .mystyle {
    font-size: 25px;
  }
</style>
<div onClick='this.classList.toggle("mystyle");'>
  example1
</div>
```

or maybe add a class to an object you clicked.

```
<style>
  .mystyle {
    font-size: 25px;
  }
</style>
<div onClick='this.classList.add("mystyle");'>
  example2
</div>
```

or, if you really want to be in control you can send the clicked object to a function and manipulate it there, in any way you like.

```
<div onClick='myFn(this);'>
  example3
</div>
<script>
    function myFn(that) {
        that.style.color = "blue";
        that.innerHTML = 'You clicked me!';
    }
</script>
```